# Send baby villagers through flowing water into soul sand elevator

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So, I was working on an infinite villager farm (Minecraft 1.17), in which the baby villagers are tricked into going into a trench for jumping on beds. The trench has water which flows all the way into a mountain's bottom where I need the baby villagers to be. Now I have to make a soul sand elevator to bring the babies to the top of the mountain where there is a comfortable prison for them, but I can't think of the proper way to connect the stream of water to the soul sand elevator. The problem is that there is space for the source blocks in the soul sand elevator to flow out and oppose the stream of water in which the baby villagers come. This causes the baby villagers to not fully reach the elevator. The thing looks like this:

[image]

[image]

Is there any tutorial on this present on the Internet? If not, do let me know the proper way if you know one.

Comment: I read your question and I was like baby villagers -- *whaaaat?!*  lol.

Answer (score 6):

By using a cobblestone wall (you can also use a fence), the baby villager can get pushed into the bubble column.
[image: mob water transport]

Make sure the water stream is 3 blocks or less. If you make it longer, like this, it will not work:
[image: dysfunctional mob water transport]

Answer (score 5):

A simple fix would be to block the source blocks from flowing with signs. There are more advanced methods as well, showcased in the vides by Wattles and ike. My preference lies with the fencepost method in ike's video, which he starts building at [1:30](https://youtu.be/z9DkZEZJ_b8?t=89).

Here it is showcased by Wattle:

Here it is showcased by ike:

Answer (score 1):

A solution to solve your problem would be to instead have the baby villagers path directly into the soul sand elevator.

[image]

All the beds are still pathable to the baby villagers.

Comment: If you put your beds immediate of the elevator, at night time the babies will sleep in the bed without going up the elevator.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just move the soul sand elevator slightly lower?

#### Key

`W`

water source block

`w`, `9`, `8`, `7`, `6`, `5`, `4`, `3`, `2`, `1`

flowing water block

`S`

soul sand

`#`

stone

#### Diagram

```
      W
######w#
      w#
987654w#
######w#
      S
```

If you remove and replace the water source block for the elevator after moving the soul sand block down one, it should stop spilling out the sides – unless I'm misremembering Minecraft water physics.

Comment: The problem is that the W up-right from the 4 will produce water and push the flow of the water backwards

Comment: @MooingDuck If you didn't have the 4, it definitely wouldn't. The only way this answer fails is if you can't have water flowing into a vertical column – but I vaguely remember making such a thing. (I haven't got access to Minecraft just now.)